# I accidently ran `mount /run`. Any way to recover without reboot?

Tags: linux, mount

I want to see what is mounted on `/run`. I could use `mount | grep /run` but instead I typed `mount /run`, which re-mount `/run` and everything inside are gone.

Now the D-Bus is dead, I can't use `systemctl` or even `reboot`.

Answer (score 15):

I found multiple tmpfs mounted on `/run`.

`umount /run` unmounted the last `mount` and fixed the problem.